# How to restore files after deletion from git file?

Tags: git, macos, gitlab, restore, git-status

I work on a project and I have a problem on my mac. After merging my branch into the main branch by the supervisor I pulled the git project with
`§ git pull`

After that I did
`§ git status`

and I recognized that there is a new file named ".DS_Store"
As I read on the internet to delete this file I used this command:
`§ find . name '.DS_Store' -type f -delete`

but unfortunately, all files in my git directory are deleted !!!!
if I type
`§ ls -a`
I got **only** the ".git" file!

Now, if I type
`§ git status`
I got a list of random files from random locations on my computer as Change to be committed and another list as Change not staged for commit and a list as Untracked files

Please help I have to get rid of this problem!

Comment: `git reset --hard` ?

Comment: it does not work. I even can not see the branches.
If i type `$git branch`I get nothing !
I think this deletion line messed up the whole project and I have to clone it again!
This is painful because I had a locally branch working on it and I stashed the changes. :(

Comment: @Ôrel The content of `git/` was also completely removed. Nothing to restore from.

Comment: @RashidKatamesh Restoring from backup or cloning anew are your only choices.

Comment: @phd how do I restore a backup?

Comment: @RashidKatamesh Do you have a backup somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I see 3 mistakes.

№1: Omitted important dash: `name` must be `-name`. The entire command must be

```
find . -name .DS_Store -type f -delete
```

№2: You haven't debugged a dangerous (because of `-delete`) command. You must have run

```
find . -name .DS_Store -type f
```

before running it with `-delete`.

№3: You don't have a local backup. You should. Make regular backups. I do small backups to my home server 3-5 times a day while I'm working; I do a full backup every Friday evening; I store full backups at the home server and remote servers at different parts of the world; I copy backups to USB disks (hard disks and SSDs) every few months.

Your current best course of action is to clone anew from the remote repository. If you don't remember the URL find it out or ask your teammates.

Answer (score -1):

As you have pulled your git repo from the server, then you should have actual repository on the server. So just delete your current local repository, and pull it again from remote server.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: At the time this answer was given, the OP still had his .git directory. Depending on how far the issue reached this could have resolved the problem for OP. Its an option, not the only potential answer.

If you still have the .git file then do yourself a huge favor and run

`git reflog`

That should give you the list of previous commands that where executed. This will include a sha near the commands similar to a `git log`

Start by iterating down that list until you get to a "fixed repository"

If this doesn't help then it you may have to re clone the git repo and start over unfortunately.

Comment: The entire content of `.git/` was completely removed. `git` commands no longer work.

Comment: Next time update the original answer that the .git directory was removed. At the time of writing the answer this information was not disclosed and would have had the potential to undo your mistakes.